# SharePoint 2010 OOTB search | Wilcard Searches

Tags: search, sharepoint-2010, wildcard

I know SharePoint 2010 supports wildcard searches in the following format "testsearch*", but not as "*testsearch".

I have files in a document library with the following file names:

- 208-12-60-LI-NK-SE-002
- 208-12-60-LI-NK-SE-003
- 208-12-60-LI-NK-SE-004
- 208-12-60-LI-NK-SE-005
- 209-12-60-LI-HK-SE-002
- 209-12-60-LI-HK-SE-003
- 209-12-60-LI-HK-SE-004
- 209-12-60-LI-HK-SE-005

In any case using wildcard searches returns results if the following search query strings are used "HK-SE-002*" or "HK-SE*". Search results are also returned if the (*) is not omitted as "HK-SE-002" and "HK-SE".

However as soon as you add more to the search string as "LI-HK-SE-002*" the wildcard searches fails to return any results. SharePoint also fails to return any results if the (*) is omitted from the search string as "LI-HK-SE-002".

I have tested this scenario on  a LIVE environment as well as on a DEV VM.

Is this a limitation of the SharePoint search functionality?

Or Are there any additional configurations that need to be made?

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Thanks,